# What is a difference flash player 18 vs 16? I have an issue only happening in Chrome flash player 18(FLEX/AS)

Tags: actionscript-3, google-chrome, flash, internet-explorer, apache-flex

If I press a button multiple times as fast as possible in chrome, it will throw an error of failed validation. In I.E its fine. The button will validate the data in the page and then load new data(paging). The validation is the first step, then loading the next data is the next step. If I click 10 times, each call must wait for the previous to finish right.

edit: I noticed when I disable chrome default flash player of 18, and use the installed version of 16, the bug is gone. Is there some major difference of 18>16?

Comment: There might be a concealed error in your code, if it behaves like that. There is a lot of differences between Chrome's Flash (PepperFlash) and Adobe Flash (ActiveX/NPAPI), it'll be hard to tell which one played against you.

Comment: I updated my OP, do you have any more input? thanks.

Comment: As @Vesper mentioned google chrome uses it's own flash player. Check your code for any errors or warning. When i got a error like this in flash IDE , i tried to publish the project in flash player v 10 and that solved my issue.